# jQuery Flip Effect API link?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for **Jquery Flip effect API**, but i could not able find the link in the website. I know **jQuery** has got very simple API for this but I am not sure it is hidden under which section. Someone please share the link with me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

#### Please check http://jqueryui.com/effect/

You can check many effects from select menu.

Comment: i want to customize everything as per my requirement so i am looking in **jQuery API**. And moreover the **jQueryUI** link what you shared is not having any Flip effect.